# My view follows the standing version of my character but not the walking version

Tags: animation, game-maker

I am making a platformer game with 4 character objects: Ninja_Standing_Right, Ninja_Walking_Right,Ninja_Walking_Left, and Ninja_Standing_Left. I have applied a view that follows Ninja_Walking_Right but whenever the ninja changes to a different object, such as Ninja_Walking_Left, the view doesn't follow it. This is obviously because Ninja_Walking_Left and Ninja_Walking_Right are different objects but how can I make it so that the view follows both Ninja_Walking_Right and Ninja_Walking_Left or whatever other method there is, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to rather change the sprite of the object than changing the whole object itself. This would both fix your problem and avoid having the same code for all player direction objects.

Comment: I know that stack overflow says to avoid comments like thanks, but you deserve it. Thanks!